# ffmpeg mp4 to webm through icecast server livestream

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, webm, icecast

I'm trying to stream huge MP4 videos (2.5Go) on an icecast server. After playing a lot with ffmpeg options to get the best quality/speed encoding settings, I'm facing a strange issue.

If I launch my ffmpeg streaming and load the video in the browser I can see it, but if I try to join it after 30s, I just get a black screen with the bottom video player bar.

Is there somewhere we can see errors ? And where ? I don't really get if the error is coming from ffmpeg / icecast / my web browser ...

If somebody can give me a clue.

Here is my setup on ffmpeg :

```
./ffmpeg -i stream/my_video.mp4 \
        -acodec libopus -b:a 64k \
        -vcodec libvpx -b:v 500K -crf 25 -vf scale=640:360 -content_type video/webm \
        -loop 365 \
        icecast://source:Password@server:8000/live.webm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2020** The link is down. Looking it up from the Internet [archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20151101231114/https://plus.google.com/+icecast/posts/iPsLfVaJ95C). Basically GOP ratio is set with the `-g option`. So give it a value of `-g 5` for example to set the value to 5.

Looking at your settings I'd guess you're not setting a GOP ratio and thus the browser, or rather the codec used by it, doesn't get any key-frame to start from.

cf. https://plus.google.com/+icecast/posts/iPsLfVaJ95C

Yes, this makes things less efficient, but that's the price for being able to tune into a stream and getting to see a picture right away. ;-)

Comment: GOP length of 5 frames is insane... at least set it to 2 seconds.  If the encoding were set correctly with clusters guaranteed to start on keyframes, would Icecast buffer correctly, keeping back a cluster or two for fast starts?

Comment: I'm afraid it probably doesn't at the moment. I'd be glad to take patches to improve it for 2.5. Yes it's insane, but if you increase it much further browsers will start failing to sync. :-(

Comment: Sorry I don't have Icecast patches for you... my server is implemented in Node.js.  It is possible to buffer WebM server-side and flush that buffer to the browsers for a fast start without all the glitching... the structure just needs to be correct, and clusters need to start with keyframes, which requires some flags in FFmpeg, or whatever your encoder is.

Comment: It's quite possible, that some more encoder tweaking would further improve the situation. Nevertheless, I hope we'll get around to beef up EBML (WebM) support for the next release.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So I've played around with the GoP value. According to the [doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites) it seems that I had to multiply by two the framerate value. Even with a -g value of 120 (4 x framerate)  got a black screen in browser ... I feel like I will never get this streaming working.

Comment: My experiments showed best reliability in browsers for a -g value below 10. Yes, that's very low. Hopefully we'll address this properly in the future, but right now it's probably the best you can do in case of Icecast. It might be possible to improve this by adjusting other parameters as suggested by Brad.

Comment: Arf, still same problem, even with a g value of 5.

Comment: Is the queue size large enough? At least for Ogg video Icecast needs increased queue size. You could also try what impact turning on and off burst on connect has, also vary the burst size.

Comment: Ok ! that works ! I had to put a `-g 10 -keyint_min 10` and actually wait for 1~2 minutes before getting video in my browser. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg site recommends a -g of twice the framerate:

[encoding for streaming sites](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites)

more on `-g` in the icecast/ffmpeg documentation:

[webm to icecast with ffmpeg](https://wiki.xiph.org/index.php?title=Icecast_Server/Streaming_WebM_to_Icecast_with_FFmpeg)

mine is streaming fine with the `-g 150`